# Python: How to generate list with items repeating in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, generate

I have two lists of items:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']
list_2 = ['C', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'C']
```

I want to create a new list with the elements that are in the two lists. Like this:

```
['A', 'C', 'C', 'D']
```

Notice that it should take in mind that any item can repeat in list several times and should be in the new list as many times as it is repeated in both lists. For instance, 'C' is repeated 2 times in list_1 and 3 times in list_2 so it appears 2 times in the result.

The classic method to do it will be:

```
import copy
result = []
list_2 = fruit_list_2.copy()
for fruit in fruit_list_1:
  if fruit in list_2:
    result.append(fruit)
    list_2.remove(fruit)
```

but I am interested to do it by generation lists: [number for number in numbers if number > 0]. Is it possible?

Comment: list comprehension is allowed?

Comment: Why is `C` in the output then if it the counts are different?

Comment: In new list need takes minimal times repeating = what exactly we have in two lists

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't terribly concerned about the ordering of the new list, you can use `collections.Counter`.

```
>>> list((Counter(list_1) & Counter(list_2)).elements())
['A', 'C', 'C', 'D']
```

`&` takes the intersection of the two as multi-sets, with the minimum count used for common elements. The `elements` method returns the items in the result as an iterator, hence the `list` wrapper`.

Comment: thanks! It is looks cool) and new for me. But i need do it by generating list.. (

Answer (score 2):

I think it's as simple as:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D']
list_2 = ['C', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'G', 'D', 'C']

list_3 = [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]

print(list_3)

# returns ['A', 'C', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: This solution will not ensure the required number of times per input appearance.

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but it has error in case:
fruit_list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'C']
fruit_list_2 = ['C', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'N', 'L', 'C']

new_list will be: ['A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'C']
but need just 3C

Comment: @kjmerf list_1 = ['A', 'A'], list_2 = ['A'] should have list_3 = ['A'] and your solution will provide list_3 = ['A', 'A']

Comment: I guess I mis-understood the question. I thought we wanted duplicates.

Comment: I understand that entries must be duplicated as many times as they appear in both lists. So list_1 = ['A', 'A', 'A'], list_2 = ['A', 'A'] should have list_3=['A', 'A']

Comment: I get it. Will leave the answer up but thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

read about [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

```
from collections import Counter

list_3 = list((Counter(list_1) & Counter(list_2)).elements())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[common for common in list_1 if common in list_2]
```

Happy learning...:)

Comment: no.. it is easy but you have bug in case: 
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'C'] list_2 = ['C', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'N', 'L', 'C'] new_list will be: ['A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'C'] - here 4C but need 3C